# State variable is not updated in onClickHandler while using Hooks for getting data from an API by a user input in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function EmpInfo() {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState(
    "http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees/"
  );
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");

  function onChangeHandler(event) {
    setInput(event.target.value);
  }

  function onClickHandler() {
    console.log("Input -> " + input);

    //Input is working as expected

    setUrl(url => url + input);
    getDataFromUrl(url);
  }

  function getDataFromUrl(url) {
    console.log(" URL ->" + url);

    // here the input value is not added to the url

    fetch(url)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          response.json();
        } else {
          throw new Error("Something went wrong");
        }
      })
      .then(data => {
        setData(data);
      })
      .catch();
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h4>Enter Employee ID </h4>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="ID" onChange={onChangeHandler} />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="button" onClick={onClickHandler} value="Search" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <h4>{url}</h4>

      //Here the updated URL with the input added to it is displayed as I click the Button

    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React hooks are executing asynchronously.
When you call `setUrl`, it will be executed in the next cycle and when you call `getDataFromUrl`, your `setUrl` is not executed yet. you should pass the new url manually to `getDataFromUrl`

```
function onClickHandler() {
    console.log("Input -> "+input)
    setUrl(url =>
        url + input
    )
    getDataFromUrl(url+input)
}
```

Comment: Yes it worked thanks, So can we use effect hook so when we see the URL is updated then we can call the getDataFromUrl, I'm new to react so just curious about this

Comment: Yes, `useEffect` fulfills what you intended to do